# How can I change the Background Resource from the first ListView visible Item?

Tags: android, listview

I'm Noob at Java Android.

I searched more about my question and I found that I can use

> listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

To get my first visible position. How can I implement a new Background Resource only to my first visible position?

I tried to do that by far.

```
View get = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() 

get.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newconversation);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method in your adapter which controls your list items views

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

You can just use this condition :

```
if(position == 0)
//set your background
```

After `convertView` has been inflated

Answer (score 0):

`getFirstVisiblePosition()` returns an Integer position.  You want to get the view at that position.

Try

`View view = list.getChildAt(list.getFirstVisiblePosition());`

Then set your background on the `view`.